# How to link AWS CloudFront distribution to AWS Elemental MediaPackage from PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, aws-elemental, aws-media-live

I want to link CloudFront from MediaPackage, This is possible from AWS Elemental MediaPackage console but
I need to do this from my coding I use PHP.

I don't see an option from CreateChannel function to quick enable as it was on console.

[image]
[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-mediapackage-2017-10-12.html#createchannel

Do I need to create from CloudFront SDK and configure all option?

This is how my auto-generated CloudFront from my Elemental MediaPackage console looks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same thing when looking through the PHP SDK MediaPackage documentation. It looks like what you will need to do is use SDK's CloudFront client to create the CloudFront distribution after creating the MediaPackage channel and endpoint. There are instructions on this page for doing this. The instructions are under the heading "Creating a Distribution from Amazon CloudFront."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/cdns-cf.html#cdns-create-cf

Comment: Thank You :) I have done the same, We don't have the option to create from MediaPackage SDK. We need to do it from CloudFront SDK.

Answer (score -1):

As you've already discovered, the MediaPackage `/origin_endpoints` API does not currently provide the option to associate a CloudFront distribution similar to the AWS MediaPackage console experience.

Since the previously suggested workaround involves querying the CloudFront API directly, I have submitted a feature request to implement this feature within the API.

As with any product feature request for an AWS service, I cannot provide any details on if or when such a feature would be implemented.